# Dumb Matlab Issue

Tags: matlab, loops

I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm rather stumped on it. I'm taking in sets of images, each with taken with a different exposure time, and measuring the mean value of the output (in DN) and the RMS of the signal. The whole point is to construct a photon transfer curve. The issue I'm running into, is that when I try to average either the signal or RMS of a window, or even a single pixel, the value stored is laughably different. This should be rather straight forward, which is why it's been so frustrating. Any insight would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
stacklength = 25;
frame = [];
frameMean = [];
framerms = [];
frameRMS = [];
t = 1;
stacknum = 99;
stackdepth = 15;
imagewidth=1944;
imageheight=2592;
uStart = 1001;
uEnd = 1001;
vStart = 1001;
vEnd = 1001;
tic;
for i=1:stacklength
    filename=sprintf('PTLstack_%d.mat' ,i);  %name files one at a time
    load(filename); 
    for u = uStart:uEnd
        for v = vStart:vEnd
            pix = double(squeeze(pixel(u,v,:)));
            pixmean = mean(pix);
            pixrms = rms(pix);
            frame(t) = pixmean;
            framerms(t) = abs(pixrms-pixmean);
            t = t+1;
        end
    end
    frameMean(i) = mean(frame);
    frameRMS(i) = mean(framerms);
    t = 1;
    disp(i);
end
toc;
```

And here are a few values I had it display for me:

```
pix
    16
    18
    21
    19
    22
    17
    19
    18
    16
    20
    18
    21
    23
    17
    20

pixmean
    19

pixrms
frame(t)
    19

framerms(t)
    18.8880

mean(frame)
    0.4404

frameMean(i)
    0.4404

**********
frameRMS(i)
    0.4404

**********
```

Please let me know if you'd like clarification on any of this. I know it can be annoying to look at a chunk of code and be expected to figure out everything that's going on in it.

Thanks a 10^6.

Comment: You should zero-initialize `frame` and `framerms`, now you're re-using the old values if the data sets have different sizes. Growing arrays in loops is inefficient anyway, so you should pre-allocate. If `uEnd`, `vEnd` etc. change across mat files, you can easily get tainted data (for instance, the second iteration uses an image of size `5000x5000`, then the next of size `1000x1000`...there are a lot of allocated-but-unset elements in this case). I suggest setting `frame=zeros(...)` before the double for loop, and the same for `framerms`, where `...` is the total number of `t` indices.

Comment: If you want to avoid tainting your variables by stray vars in the mat file, try loading into a struct: `tmpvars = load(...); pixel = tmpvars.pixel;`. This way no other parameters can get loaded. Come to think of it, you could as well do `load(...,'pixel')`

Comment: t goes to 15 every time. I take sets of 15 images at a particular integration time, then increase the integration time and do it again. The strategy is to take a mean of the output for a particular pixel and save it to a vector. Then, take the mean value of that vector. That way I can average the light response over a certain window of the chip. I had frame & framerms pre-allocated before, but went back to generic arrays to simplify as much as possible. There's something else wonky going on. frameMean(i) and frameRMS(i) are both well below the minimum value, of around 15.

Comment: You can take the mean through a stack of images in one shot, you realise? Get rid of the loops and t.

Answer (score 1):

The results suggest that you have some stray zeros in your `frame` variables, lowering the mean. Exactly where these are coming in isn't clear to me, partly because this is a not very Matlab-styled way of handling this sort of code.

A shortcut, although inelegant, to fixing this would be to tell it to take the mean only of the non-zeros:

```
frameMean(i) = mean(frame(frame~=0));
```

However if you have spare zeros you may also have spurious data of some other sort in there.

A better solution is to rid yourself of those loops and incremental variable etc. altogether. Presuming that your images are being loaded as an image stack of size (x,y,15), you can take mean and rms across the region you desire in a single go:

```
pix = pix(ustart:uend,vstart:vend,:); % take window area of choice
frame = mean(pix,3); % make mean 
framerms = rms(pix,3);
framerms = abs(framerms-frame);
```

The outputs here are 2D matrices across the frame; to take the mean across the whole frame the easiest is to use : to index all elements, e.g. `mean(frame(:))`.

Comment: Ahh, great advice. Thanks much. No one has ever, nor will likely ever accuse me of coding elegantly. I am still running into an issue of finding the RMS of each pixel for every frame and averaging it. I've decided that the rms() function isn't really what I'm looking for, but what I really need is sqrt(var(pix(u,v,:))). I'm trying to measure the noise in every pixel. I don't see how that's possible without resorting to loops. Ideas?

Comment: Almost every function works on the matrix level; you should always be able to work on an entire image/image stack, you should never need to loop pixel by pixel. Look for a `dim` input to a function (which like `mean` and `rms`, `dim` has) to tell the function which dimension you want to work across.